# How to connect with Pyodbc with function?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm having an issue where I cannot connect to a database when starting the program with a function.  If I don't start it with a function, it works just fine.
My program grabs a computer name from serverlist.txt and looks it up in the database.  It then gives me a "Location ID" for that computer.

This version works:

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import pypyodbc

def replaceid(servername):
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        SQLCommand = ("SELECT Name, Location_ID "
            "FROM dbo.I_Location "   # table name
            "with (nolock)"
            "WHERE Name = ?")
        Values = [servername]
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        results = cursor.fetchone()
        if results:

            print (" Name: " + results[0] + " Location ID: " + str(results[1]))
            print (" ")
        else:
            print (" Location ID for " + servername + " does not exist.")
            print (" ")
            connection.close()
    except:
        print("Database is down or you are not connected to network.")
        exit()

def grab(servername):
# copy config from remote computer

    source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/Administrator/'
    dest = "."
    file = "Admin.config"
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, file))
        try:
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))

        except:
            print (" Local directory you are copying to does not exist.")
    else: 
        pass

    replaceid(servername)



os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
array = []
with open("serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:

        try:
            connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=mydbx;Database=WinOasis;Trusted_Connection=yes;') 
        except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[0]
            if sqlstate == '28000':
                print ("You do not have access.")
        grab(servername.strip())
```

When I add the start() function at the bottom, it does not work.  It moves to the exception that says 
    Database is down or you are not connected to network.

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import pypyodbc

def replaceid(servername):
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        SQLCommand = ("SELECT Name, Location_ID "
            "FROM dbo.I_Location "   # table name
            "with (nolock)"
            "WHERE Name = ?")
        Values = [servername]
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        results = cursor.fetchone()
        if results:

            print (" Name: " + results[0] + " Location ID: " + str(results[1]))
            print (" ")
        else:
            print (" Location ID for " + servername + " does not exist.")
            print (" ")
            connection.close()
    except:
        print("Database is down or you are not connected to network.")
        exit()

def grab(servername):
# copy config from remote computer

    source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/Administrator/'
    dest = "."
    file = "Admin.config"
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, file))
        try:
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))

        except:
            print (" Local directory you are copying to does not exist.")
    else: 
        pass

    replaceid(servername)

def start():
    # Option 1
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    array = []
    with open("serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
        for servername in f:

            try:
                connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=mydbx;Database=WinOasis;Trusted_Connection=yes;') 
            except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
                sqlstate = ex.args[0]
                if sqlstate == '28000':
                    print ("You do not have access.")
            grab(servername.strip())

start()
```

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you put connection inside the start function it becomes a local object and the other functions can not get the connection !!!

you have to pass the connection as an object to each function if they are using same connection !!!

```
grab(servername.strip(),connection)
def grab(servername ,connection):
def replaceid(servername,connection):
```

change like this and it should be fine (put grab function inside try part)